# Rename 'Cancel' on modal sheet in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, watchos

The Apple documentation gives some user interface design tips on modal sheets including renaming Cancel to something like Dismiss where relevant. But there's no guide whether this is possible in SwiftUI.

There's a link that takes you to setTitle for Watchkit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619570-settitle

But is there something equivalent for a SwiftUI Watch app?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `ToolbarItem` with the `.cancellationAction` placement works:

```swift
struct MySheet: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        Text("The Content Of Sheet")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                Button("Custom") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this still applicable for watchOS 9? I tried it and it doesn't display on my app